# Understanding variance calculations in scipy.optimise.curve_fit

Tags: scipy, confidence-interval, scipy-optimize, non-linear-regression, covariance-matrix

I'm trying to use Scipy's [`scipy.optimise.curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html#scipy.optimize.curve_fit) to calculate the parameters for a non-linear least squares fit of my data to a function. I have 2-3 response values for each value of my explanatory variable. Each of these *individual* response values is assumed to be errorless.

I've done a fair bit of forum searching online but I still need help understanding what I should be specifying for the `absolute_sigma` and `sigma` arguments and what effect these have on the output variance-covariance matrix, as I need the matrix for calculating confidence intervals for my fitted parameters and confidence bands for my function via the Delta method.

Any advice would be very much appreciated!

Comment: How is it possible that multiple different dependent values at a single value of an independent variable are errorless? Surely only one of them represents the central tendency

Comment: @Reinderien these are readouts from an experiment - each response value is the readout from an experimental unit (i.e. multiple experimental units have been tested at each level of the explanatory variable)